# Facebook PHP SDK: how to display login dialog automatically?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My code cannot display the permission dialog when a user connect to my Facebook application. Instead of the login page, I got a 404 error.

My code:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
require './config.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
  'secret' => $fb_secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$userData = null;
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $userData = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream',
));
}


    <div id="loginWrapper">
<?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
```

I have also tried to put directly an personalized URL (like bellow) and I got the same 404 error.

```
$loginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$fb_app_id."&redirect_uri=".$fb_app_url."&scope=publish_stream";
```

## **UPDATE 1:**

Otherwise when I try to Login directly through the server (from http://mydomain/application/index.php), I got a redirection to Facebook website to the URL below and got this error message:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication&state=f8cd945d8a9aefcd0b439fecd8515a68&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&scope=publish_stream
```

[image: http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/661/screenshot20111216at151.png]

## **UPDATE 2:**

Here my application configuration:

And the message I got when I try to access directly from the app link: apps.facebook.com/myapplication/ without be logged

[image: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/7721/screenshot20111216at173.png]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If it just doesn't work when you're not logged in, may it be that your App runs in Sandbox Mode? You can check if it's enabled in the "Advanced Settings" of your App.

Answer (score 0):

The **status_update** permission you are using in the scope for the loginUrl is not a valid permission. Take a look at the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

That could be your problem.

Also remember, that if a user has already authorized your app, they will not see the permission dialog again on subsequent logins. They will only be taken through the facebook login procedure.

EDIT:

Take a look at the image I've attached, facebook will on redirect to the url you specify in the site url field in app settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank your for the advise. But it didn't solve my problem. Facebook still return me an error even if I use only scope=publish_stream.

Comment: ah ok. From your update, it seems like it might be related to the way your FB App is configured.

Comment: I suppose you could do the following:

instead of redirecting to http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication from the loginUrl, redirect back to your custom domain http://mydomain/application/my_redirect.php and inside my_redirect, you could redirect back to the FB app url after the login has been successful.

I don't think it's meant to be used like that though, but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: I understand the manipulation but actually the problem is that the user can only access to my app from the apps.facebook.com/myapplication URL. He is not supposed to go through mydomain/application/...

Comment: I've tried to change the website link and it still doesn't work. I have updated my post by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the update of your post:** Go to the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and select the App you're getting this error for. Click edit settings and enter the domain your App is hosted on/you're redirecting to into the "App Domain" field. Now just save and it should work.

**Edit (solution from comment above):** If it just doesn't work when you're not logged in, may it be that your App runs in Sandbox Mode? You can check if it's enabled in the "Advanced Settings" of your App.

Comment: I still have the same problem: "The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive." I have added the domain, which is: php.quotations.s155.eatj.com

Comment: Which domain did you add to the App Domain list? The domain of your redirect_uri must be in that list (in this case facebook.com)

Comment: I've added apps.facebook.com and facebook.com and I got the same errors.

Comment: In your sample code you used 'scope' but the link I get redirected to uses the 'perms' key which is not valid anymore

Comment: I noticed this too. I don't know why the api return me the perms instead of the scope.